Do people say "valedictorian" in British English, and if not, do they have an equivalent?
Oxford dictionary says

valedictorian noun  /ˌvælɪdɪkˈtɔːriən/  /ˌvælɪdɪkˈtɔːriən/ (North
American English) ​the student who has the highest grades in a
particular group of students and who gives the valedictory speech at a
graduation ceremony

But it doesn't say a British equivalent for it.
So, I deduce British people also say "valedictorian".
Do people say "valedictorian" in British English, and if not, do they have an equivalent?

While there are some schools with unique traditions, British schools traditionally don't have American-style graduation ceremonies; they may have a head boy or head girl giving a speech at special occasions, but this role isn't determined by grades. Although in recent years there has been a move towards more American-style graduation ceremonies, that doesn't require a formal title. Questions about education systems are off-topic though.

"British" is not a useful way to discuss UK educational matters: England, Wales, Scotland, Northern Ireland all have different systems.
It seems to me that Michael Harvey's answer is from an English perspective, where the idea of valedictorian may be utterly foreign.
But in contrast, in Scotland every school would have its Dux: the pupil in the final year who had the best set of examination results. This was quite different from being Head Boy or Girl. The nearest thing to a graduation was the Annual Prizegiving, where some distinguished alumnus would give an inspirational speech, the prizes and a medal for the dux would be handed out, and (usually) the Dux would briefly propose a vote of thanks to all involved.
[65 years since I got my dux medal!]
